# Windows bootloader doesn't come up after installing via Wubi

Tags: windows, wubi

I downloaded the Ubuntu ISO, burned it to a disk and rebooted my computer to run Wubi. My first issue was that before the Wubi options came up, it said Error: Prefix not set.

I tried the second option (Install Ubuntu), but that kept giving me a black screen, where nothing was happening, so I manually restarted my computer. I then went into the first option (Try Ubuntu without installing), and from there chose the Install Ubuntu program.

However, now that it's installed (and my C:\ drive has been shrunk), the Windows bootloader doesn't come up to give me the option of booting into Ubuntu.

Any ideas?

Also, I'm running Windows 7, 64 bit.

EDIT: It doesn't show Ubuntu as being installed in Add/Remove programs, but my C:\ drive has definitely shrunk. There's also no C:\Ubuntu. I'm starting to think it didn't get installed or something. Is there a way to reclaim the space into my C:\ drive and restart the installation?

EDIT2: Apparently it created a partition? Here's what disk manager says: http://files.droplr.com/files_production/acc_1820/pKhU?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJSVQN3Z4K7MT5U2A&Expires=1338226683&Signature=JR2w%2FzC023uCFMqCE407EVRrfuU%3D&response-content-disposition=inline%3B+filename%3D%22Screenshot+on+5.29.2012+at+1.36.58+AM.png%22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way for installing Ubuntu is a separate partition.  You may do a control of the actual situation.  Download Gparted (it is for free) http://gparted.sourceforge.net/download.php, burn it to a disc, and boot you computer from this disc.  This will give you an idea what is going on.  You can make a separate partition for ubuntu (ext4) and a swap (max. 2Gb), and install Ubuntu in this partition. See here: http://opensource-sidh.blogspot.com/2011/10/install-ubuntu-1110-and-windows-dual.html

Comment: Thanks! I'd definitely want to install onto a seperate partition, but for some reason the partition that's being created isn't being detected by Windows?

Comment: Thanks dude, just got it all sorted. I'll leave this here in case anyone sees this in the future:
gparted told me that I had partitioned my hard drive (the Ubuntu partition was ext4 like you said), so I assumed that I accidently hadn't used wubi. I tried re-installing with the CD, but still no like, the bootloader wouldn't come up. What I had to do was find what drive Ubuntu was installed on (sda6) and run the following commands from the Ubuntu live CD:

```sudo mount /dev/[location of ubuntu] /mnt```
```sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sda```

Comment: @ChintanParikh: that's worth putting as a separate answer, as it shows how you fixed your system.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a partition for Ubuntu (ext3 or most likely ext4), Windows is unable to recognize that partition - it just doesn't know how to read or write to ext3/4 file systems. On the other hand, in Ubuntu, you can easily access NTFS file systems which are used by Microsoft Windows.

However there seems to be a couple of solutions for this as well. I have not tried them out.

[How to Access Linux Partitions (ext2, ext3, ext4) From Windows in Dual-Boot System?](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-access-linux-partitions-ext2-ext3-from-windows-in-dual-boot-system/)

Comment: Funnily enough, I wanted to install it via Wubi because I thought partitioning my hard drive might be too difficult and I didn't want to mess up my computer - it turns out I accidently installed Ubuntu on a new partition and everything works great!